# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS : cannot access fixed IP addresses after recent update

Tags: networking, updates, printing, ubiquity

Been running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS successfully for the past 6 months. All of a sudden I do not seem to be able to access any of the fixed IP addresses on my network anymore. Specifically :
1] I cannot print anymore (printer has a fixed IP address). Check : my wife can, and she is also running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on her laptop.
2] Cannot access my Ubiquity Cloud Key/controller (also on a fixed IP address). Check : I can access it from a phone app, but not from my laptop.
I also tried to turn the Ubuntu firewall off. Didn't help either.
The only thing I can think about is a software update which I ran earlier this week, but I may be wrong.
Thank you in advance for throwing me a bone, still learning Ubuntu :)

Comment: 1) check the IP of your phone (Settings > About phone > Status, on android). 2) check the IP of your laptop (`ifconfig`) they have to be on the same subnet unless you have routing in place to link differing subnets together (The first two-three numbers must be the same in the ip-numbers).

Comment: Feeling embarrassed, but you nailed it ! I had been setting up several VLANS to accommodate a camera system recently and one way or another my laptop did not connect to the main LAN anymore. Thank you so much !